# sscanf() hex ints into an array of ints vs. unsigned chars

Tags: c, types, scanf, strtol

I am converting a string representation of a mac address into an array of `UINT8`s defined as `unsigned char`. I am curious why `sscanf()` will read all 0s when I read into an array of `UINT8`s and actual values when I read into an array of regular 32 bit `int`s. Its almost like it's chopping off the 8 bits of the wrong end of the int.

```
char *strMAC = "11:22:33:AA:BB:CC";

typedef unsigned char UINT8;
UINT8 uMAC[6];

int iMAC[6];

sscanf( (const char*) strMac, 
        "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", 
        &uMAC[0], &uMAC[1], &uMAC[2], &uMAC[3], &uMAC[4], &uMAC[5] );
printf( "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", 
        uMAC[0], uMAC[1], uMAC[2], uMAC[3], uMAC[4], uMAC[5] );
// output: 0:0:0:0:0:0

sscanf( (const char*) strMac, 
        "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", 
        &iMAC[0], &iMAC[1], &iMAC[2], &iMAC[3], &iMAC[4], &iMAC[5] );
printf( "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", 
        iMAC[0], iMAC[1], iMAC[2], iMAC[3], iMAC[4], iMAC[5] );
// output: 11:22:33:AA:BB:CC
```

Update: `%hhx` will work for C99 and above, but I have an old codebase so I ended up going with `strtoul()`:

```
char *str = strMac;
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++, str+=3) {
    uMAC[i] = strtoul(str, NULL, 16);
}
```

Comment: You are invoking an undefined behavior here, so any explanation provided won't be complete.

Comment: `char *strMac = "11:22:33:AA:BB:CC";`?

Comment: Not the main issue here, yet no need for `(const char*)` in `sscanf( (const char*) strMac,...`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** - The first snippet invkoes UB because of argument type mismatch.

---

To elaborate, quoting the requirement of argument type for `%x` format specifier, from `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.2, `fscanf()` function, (*emphasis mine*)

> `x`   Matches an optionally signed hexadecimal integer, whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the `strtoul()` function with the value 16 for the base argument. **The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to unsigned integer.**

So, while using

```
 sscanf( (const char*) strMac, 
    "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", 
    &uMAC[0], &uMAC[1], &uMAC[2], &uMAC[3], &uMAC[4], &uMAC[5] );
```

in your code, you're supplying wrong type of argument for `%x`. According to the standard, again,

> [...]. Unless assignment suppression was indicated by a `*`, the
>   result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following the format argument that has not already received a conversion result. If this object does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined.

So, providing a wrong type as argument is invoking  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

---

**Solution:**

To indicate that you're going to supply a (signed or unsigned) `char` type argument, you need to use the format specifier prefixed with the `hh` length modifier, like `%hhx` with `scanf()` family.

Comment: @EOF How about now? :-)

Comment: I have no control over my build environment (and it is obfuscated), so I don't know what version of C we use. %hhx silently fails: I get no compiler error, but it does not work. But I don't understand how is  sscanf( strMac, "%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx", &uMAC[0], &uMAC[1], &uMAC[2], &uMAC[3], &uMAC[4], &uMAC[5] ) a valid statement if hh is not a valid format specifier.

Comment: @ubtac `%hhx` was added in 1999. If you have an older environment you will have to read into `unsigned int` objects and then copy the results one by one into your char array.

Comment: @ubtac another option would be to simply not use scanf

Comment: @MattMcNabb that's what I ended up going with, just curios how `%hhx` is valid in (presumably) ANSI C.